# How to close Materialize modal only when user clicks on close btn?

Tags: modal-dialog, materialize

I want to close modal ONLY when user clicks on close button. I know, how to do this in Bootstrap. Could you help with Materialize?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can customize the behavior of Materialize modal using Options which can be found [Here](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) at the bottom of the page

change option `dismissible` to `false` (which by default in modal plugin is `true`) so modal only get closed when click on `close` button.

```
$('.modalselector').leanModal({
      dismissible: false
);
```

Example Modal

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.modal-trigger').leanModal({
  dismissible: false
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/css/materialize.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: $("#modal_id").modal('open', {
      dismissible: true,
      complete: function() { console.log('Close modal'); }
   })    for close and open put dismissible en false, that for materialize

Answer (score 6):

You can close the modal with the following code:

```
$('#modalname').closeModal(); or  $('#modalname').modal('close');
```

Answer (score 5):

`$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modal1').openModal({
        dismissible:false
    });
});`

Try This It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Below code worked for me with materialize.css 1.0.0

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

   var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');
   var instances = M.Modal.init(elems,{
    dismissible:false
   });
   
   var singleModalElem = document.querySelector('#login-page');
   var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(singleModalElem);
   instance.open();
  
   })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="login-page" class="modal">
 <form class="login-form">
  <div class="row">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
    <input class="validate" id="nick_name" type="text">
    <label for="nick_name" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Nick Name</label>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
    <a href="#" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12">Entra</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the methods worked for me. However, this did,

```
$('#modal1').closeModal({ dismissible: true});
```

Comment: `$('#modal1').openModal({ dismissible: false});` did it!

Answer (score 1):

The leanModal(), openModal(), and closeModal() all failed for me.  Things must have changed since then.  Instead:

```
$("#modal1").modal({
    dismissible: false
  });
```

or even just calling the modal a second time:

```
$("#modal1").modal();
```

Comment: Materialize switched from leanModal to modal with version 0.97.8

Answer (score 0):

Just set the data-backdrop property to static.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to insert button for closing the modal (sometime CSS conflict won't allow the modal to close) use this:

```
<span 
   class="modal-action modal-close"
   style="float:right; font-size:30px;" 
   onclick="$('#myModal2').closeModal();"
>
X
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across the need to do something similar and thought I'll share this for others who are looking for it too. I'm using Materialize 1.0.0 and none of the suggestions above worked for me. Basically, we want to be able to have control over the modal's 'dismissible' property and change it whenever we want, from wherever we want and it shouldn't matter if it is before or after the modal is open. The most elegant way I found was to do it this way. This will control the modal's behavior from disappearing when a user clicks outside of its area.

```
    var m = M.Modal.getInstance(modal);
    m.options.dismissible = true|false;
```

where the modal param is your modal div.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript, this is the way.

The span element that will close the modal.

```
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
```

When you want to click the X to close the modal you can use this.

```
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

If you are clicking outside of modal this will close the modal.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
if(event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".modal4").addClass('modal-close');
```

Where modal4 is class of modal you want to close

Answer (score 0):

In Vue Js, By using [materialize-css package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-css)

- Install package `npm i materialize-css`
- import the package `import M from 'materialize-css';`
- Attach the code below in your *eventListener* such as **click**

```js
methods: {
    closeMaterializeModal(){
       var elem = document.getElementById("modal4");
      var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
      instance.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Below code worked for me.

```
$('#modal1').closeModal();
```

Reference: [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/modals.html#!)